# Javascript select only one element in class

Tags: javascript

I have few div classes in my document. I want to click on any of the div class and to get fullscreen of div element. Currently i can do it only with `document.getElementById("1")`. And i don't want to use jQuery just pure JavaScript.

#### Here is my code:

```
<html !DOCTYPE>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript trening</title>
        <style>
            .videoFrame{
                width:100px;
                height:100px;
                margin-bottom:10px;
                background:#000;
            }
            
            .videoFrame:nth-child(2){
                background:#cadaef;
            }
            
            .videoFrame:nth-child(3){
                background:#aed924;
            }
            
            .videoFrame:nth-child(4){
                background:#491356;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="videoFrame">
        </div>
        <div class="videoFrame" id="1">
        </div>
        <div class="videoFrame">
        </div>
        <div class="videoFrame">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            
        var oneDoc = document.getElementById("1");
        oneDoc.onclick = fullScreenDiv;
        
        function fullScreenDiv(){
            if(oneDoc.requestFullscreen){
                oneDoc.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (oneDoc.mozRequestFullScreen){
                oneDoc.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if(oneDoc.webkitRequestFullscreen){
                oneDoc.webkitRequestFullscreen();
            } else if (select.msRequestFullscreen) {
                oneDoc.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
            
        }
        
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a click handler on your `body`, or any other parent element. That handler is triggered when you click any of the child elements. Then just check the target element and see if it has the class you want to trigger from.

There's an example below. The event is triggered on any of the `videoFrame` elements, but not the other one.

```js
var body = document.querySelector("body");
body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (hasClass(target, "videoFrame")) {
      fullScreenDiv(target);
  } else {
    alert("not this one");  
  }
})

function hasClass(element, cls) {
  return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

function fullScreenDiv(oneDoc){
 if(oneDoc.requestFullscreen){
  oneDoc.requestFullscreen();
 } else if (oneDoc.mozRequestFullScreen){
  oneDoc.mozRequestFullScreen();
 } else if(oneDoc.webkitRequestFullscreen){
  oneDoc.webkitRequestFullscreen();
 } else if (select.msRequestFullscreen) {
  oneDoc.msRequestFullscreen();
 }
}
```

```css
.videoFrame{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 background:#000;
}

.videoFrame:nth-child(2){
 background:#cadaef;
}

.videoFrame:nth-child(3){
 background:#aed924;
}

.videoFrame:nth-child(4){
 background:#491356;
}

.notThisOne {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  background:#F00;  
}
```

```html
<div class="videoFrame">
</div>
<div class="videoFrame" id="1">
</div>
<div class="videoFrame">
</div>
<div class="videoFrame">
</div>
<div class="notThisOne"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('videoFrame')[index]` where `index` is the div you want to access (0-based off course), so in your case index would be one

There are many methods on the document object to select DOM elements, all of them except for `getElementById` and `querySelector` return a nodeList (similar to an array) of elements, so you will have to access the element you're interested in by specifying the index

If you would like to add an event handler to all of these divs you will have to loop through this nodeList:

```
var videoFrames = document.getElementsByClassName('videoframe');
for(int i = 0; i < videoFrames.length; i++) {
     videoFrames[i].onclick = //event handler
}
```

Comment: yes i know that but how can i get [index] when i click on some of class?

Comment: From your question it wouldn't make any sense to know what the index of the div is, but you can access the element you clicked by using `this` in the event handler: `function eventHandler() { console.log(this) } ` Try this one. FYI: in any function `this` is a reference to the object that called the function, in event handlers for the dom `this` usually is the dom element